# Undefined citations using ACS example files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm trying to prepare a document based the American Chemical Society manuscript sample files, available [here](http://pubs.acs.org/page/4authors/submission/tex.html) under the 'Standard submission option'. However, when I compile the unmodified `achemso-demo.tex` file, I get warnings that each of the citations is undefined, and they don't show up in the document. I have `achemso-demo.tex` in the same directory as `achemso.bib`.

I'm new to LaTeX and don't really know where to start troubleshooting. I'm working in Texmaker using the LaTeX build option.

Comment: Did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (or at least did this happen automatically)? You'll know that BibTeX ran as there should be a `.blg` file: take a look at that and edit in any errors it gives.

Comment: I can't find a `.blg` file.

Comment: OK, so whatever the Texmaker build option does isn't running BibTeX. Please try doing this 'by hand': often the easiest way is at the Command Line/Terminal. Which operating system do you use?

Comment: OSX 10.7. Ran BibTeX through texmaker; this seems to work. Feel fre e to post as an answer.

Comment: Looks like one of our 'common' questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number. Is it be OK to dupe to that?

Comment: That would be fine by me.